# Regex match tags with specific text within

Tags: xml, regex, match

I have an XML document where I am trying to match the full tag if it contains `sometextv2` within. Here's the sample dataset I am working with:

```
<mm_reportitem>
    <mm_file>file.cfm</mm_file>
    <mm_displaystr><![CDATA[ <cfinvoke component="/sometextv2" ]]></mm_displaystr>
</mm_reportitem>
<mm_reportitem>
    <mm_file>file.cfm</mm_file>
    <mm_displaystr><![CDATA[ <cfinvoke component = "/sometext" ]]></mm_displaystr>
</mm_reportitem>
<mm_reportitem>
    <mm_file>file.cfm</mm_file>
    <mm_displaystr><![CDATA[ <cfinvoke component="sometextv2" ]]></mm_displaystr>
</mm_reportitem>
```

I'm working with the following that I put together from a couple different sources:

```
<mm_reportitem[^>]*>([\s\S]*?).*sometextv2.*([\s\S]*?)<\/mm_reportitem>
```

This is matching the full tag I am wanting. However, this appears to be matching both `sometext` and `sometextv2`.

What am I missing so that only `sometextv2` gets matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
<mm_reportitem>[\s\S]{10,200}sometextv2\"[\s\S]*?<\/mm_reportitem>
```

I just add the {10,150} to avoid more than one mm_reportitem in one result. I think it's a problem with regex too "greedy" in this strange case...

Comment: I was able to modify this to allow for attributes in the `mm_reportitem` node and got this to work perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Your regex looks way too complicated to me.

```
<tag.*sometextv2.*</tag>
```

Works on all examples you posted. Does that work for you?

Comment: I was able to provide an actual dataset I am working with. Please see original post. I tried your suggestion, but it's not matching. Perhaps it was due to the lack of new lines within the tags?

Comment: Just add these as you go...
    <mm_reportitem>\n.*\n.*sometextv2.*\n</mm_reportitem>

From here you can make it more strict or lax as you need it.

Comment: Following your example, I created a test case here. However, I am still not getting the match: http://regexr.com/39qt0

Also, there may be 2 new lines within `<mm_reportitem>`, 3, 4, etc. It's not all consistent so explicitly defining new lines in the expression likely won't be reliable in this case.